# Powershell script not running or giving and output

Tags: c#, powershell, outlook

I am running the following code with a script that is supposed to change User Principal Names for our Outlook accounts when an employee gets a name change.

The code takes about 30-60 seconds to run when I call `ps.Invoke()`, then when I inspect the `results` variable in the debugger it only contains an empty list. I then check to see if the account UPN got changed and it hasn't. However, if I copy and paste the script string in a powershell window, it executes and works just fine.

Does anyone have any ideas?

### The C# code:

```
public bool RenameOutlookAccount(string originalEmail, string newEmail)
{
    bool result = false;

    try
    {
        // Set up credentials
        string username = _config.AppSettings.Settings["PowershellUser"].Value;
        string password = _config.AppSettings.Settings["PowershellPassword"].Value;

        // Create the PowerShell object
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

        // Add the script
        string script = String.Format(@"$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString ""{0}"" -AsPlainText -Force; $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (""{1}"", $secpasswd); $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection; Import-PSSession $Session; Import-Module Msonline; Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred; Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -UserPrincipalName {2} -NewUserPrincipalName {3}; Remove-PSSession $Session", password, username, originalEmail, newEmail);
        ps.AddScript(script);

        // Run
        var results = ps.Invoke();

        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

### The (formatted) powershell command I am running:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString {password} -AsPlainText -Force

$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ({username}, $secpasswd)

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session

Import-Module Msonline

Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred

Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -UserPrincipalName {oldUPN} -NewUserPrincipalName {newUPN}

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: Is your exchange server in the cloud or local? You mention Exchange, but 'User Principal Names' are properties that normally reside in Active Directory. I do not know how Outlook.com tie together Exchange and AD. Unless you are referring to Mailbox Alias's...

Comment: I am going to remove the exchange-server tag because I see how that would cause confusion. The exchange server is in the cloud (Microsoft Azure).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `ps.Streams.Error` and `ps.Streams.Warning` to see if there is anything in there that might point you in the right direction.  Note that your catch will get invoked *if* there is a terminating error.  Many commands fail with non-terminating errors.  Another option is set the global variable `ErrorActionPreference` to `Stop` using `ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable()`.  That will convert all non-terminating errors into terminating errors which your catch statement can then catch.

Comment: This helped, thanks. The errors I was apparently receiving are `The specified module 'Msonline' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.` and `"The term 'Set-MsolUserPrincipalName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."` I'm not sure how to fix that, but at least I know what the errors are now.

Comment: @grantmc Is the problematic module bit specific?  The Microsoft.Exchange endpoint is a 64-bit endpoint.  If the Msonline module is only available in 32-bit PowerShell, it will fail to load.  You may have to resort to doing the 32-bit work in a 32-bit PowerShell job on that remote machine e.g. `Start-Job {ipmo msonline; ...} -RunAs32`

Comment: [This is the module](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39267). I downloaded the 64-bit version, so I don't think that is the issue. I ran `Get-Module -ListAvailable` from within a PowerShell terminal and it found the MSOnline module. Then when I ran that same command from within my C# application, MSOnline was not listed. So for some reason it is not finding that module.